# Can someone help me translate this phrase?

Tags: translation

What is the correct translation for the phrase

> "I left my heart in Seoul"

in Korean
It's for a tattoo I want to get!
thankyou!

Answer (score 3):

> I left my heart in Seoul

내 마음을 서울에 놔뒀다

or

내 마음을 서울에 두고 갔다

or

내 마음을 서울에 남겨 뒀다

The first one is the best, and most likely what you want.

Answer (score 1):

> Consider usage of "leave"

1) leave a patient to the doctor's care.

환자를 의사에게 맡기다

2) I left my child in my sister's care.

나는 어린아이를 누님에게 맡겼다

> Given sentence can be translated directly as 나는 마음을 서울에 맡기다. Hence, 나는 서울에서 추억이 있다 (I had a good old memory in Seoul).

reference : http://dic.daum.net/word/view.do?wordid=kew000023615&supid=keu000159080

Comment: You're using 맡기다, which means to assign, entrust or ask someone to do something for you, as in the English sentence "Can I leave this [task] to you?". But the sentence that the OP wants to translate means to actually leave something behind. Maybe a "내 마음을 서울에게 맡겼다" could work, as you mentioned, but that sounds weird anyway.